# Problems Integration ERC-20 Smartcontract, and Interface with Metamask

Tags: erc-20, metamask

I got problems connecting my ERC-20 tokensale smart contract via interface with Metamask.
Everytime I see a popup that I have to connect my wallet while it’s already connected. Another problem is that it’s telling me that I don't have enough tokens while the wallet is filled.

Node.js is installed on our Linux server, etc.

1. Here’s the smart contract:

   ```
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^ 0.8.0;

    interface Firenza {
        function totalSupply() external view returns(uint256);
        function balanceOf(address account) external view returns(uint256);
        function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);
        function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);

    }

    contract SaleController{
        event TokenPurchased(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount, uint256 _bnb);
        event ClaimedToken(address indexed _owner, uint256 _stakeId, uint256 _date);

        Firenza Token;

     bool public is_preselling;
    address payable owner;
    address payable tokenSource = payable(0x53********************)); 
    address payable fundreceiver = payable(0x9146********************)); 

    address payable fundreceiver;
    uint256 soldTokens;
    uint256 receivedFunds;


    struct tokenVesting{
        uint256 amount;        
        uint256 date_added;     
        uint256 redeem_date;    
        uint256 redeem_count;
    }

    uint256 redemptionCount = 4; //4 times to redeem
    uint256 lockDays = 30; //1 month duration every redemption (total of 120 days or 4 months)
    uint256 rewardRate = 5; //7% reward for vesting the tokens

    uint256 public RecordId;
    mapping(uint256 => tokenVesting) idVesting; 
    mapping(uint256 => address) recordIdOwner;   

    constructor(Firenza _tokenAddress)  {
        Token = _tokenAddress;
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
       is_preselling = true;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "invalid owner");
        _;
    }

    //buy tokens
    function tokensale(uint256 _amount ) public payable returns(bool)  {
        require(is_preselling, "pre selling is over.");

        uint256 _rewardAmount = (_amount * rewardRate) / 100; //get total reward for vesting
        uint256 _totalTokens = _amount + _rewardAmount; //total totens (principal + reward)

        RecordId += 1; //auto increment for every record

        //save new vesting record
        tokenVesting storage _vesting = idVesting[RecordId];
        _vesting.amount = _totalTokens;
        _vesting.date_added = block.timestamp;
        _vesting.redeem_date = block.timestamp + (lockDays * 1 days); //set 1st redemption date (+30 days)

        //track down the owner of the record id
        recordIdOwner[RecordId] = msg.sender;

        //transfer tokens to contract address
        Token.transferFrom(tokenSource, address(this), _totalTokens);

        //transfer bnb or network native coin
        fundreceiver.transfer(msg.value);

        soldTokens += _amount;
        receivedFunds += msg.value;

        emit TokenPurchased(msg.sender, _amount, msg.value);
        return true;
    }

    function Redeem(uint256 _id) public returns(bool)  {

        //verify the owner of the stake record
        address _recordOwner = recordIdOwner[_id];
        require(_recordOwner == msg.sender, "invalid owner");

        tokenVesting storage _vesting = idVesting[_id];

        //validate if total redemption is not greater than 4 or (redemption count)
        require(_vesting.redeem_count < redemptionCount, "already redeemed");

        //validate if redemption date is ready
        uint256 _redeemDate = _vesting.redeem_date;  
        require(block.timestamp >= _redeemDate, "not yet ready to redeem");

        uint256 _redeemAmount = _vesting.amount / redemptionCount; //amount every redemption (divided by number of redemption or 4)

        _vesting.redeem_count += 1; //update count of redemption max of 4
        _vesting.redeem_date = block.timestamp + (lockDays * 1 days); // update date for next redemption +30 days 

        //tokens will be transferred to user's wallet address
        Token.transfer(msg.sender, _redeemAmount);

        emit ClaimedToken(msg.sender, _id, block.timestamp);
        return true;
    }

    function getTokenSupply() public view returns(uint256){
        return Token.totalSupply();
    }

    function getTokenbalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256){
        return Token.balanceOf(_address);
    }

    function totalSoldTokens() public view returns(uint256){
        return soldTokens;
    }
    function totalReceivedFunds() public view returns(uint256){
        return receivedFunds;
    }

    function getbalance()  public onlyOwner {
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }


    function SetReceiver(address payable _fund) public onlyOwner {
        fundreceiver = _fund;
    }


    function SetPreSellingStatus() public onlyOwner {
        if (is_preselling) {
            is_preselling = false;
        } else {
            is_preselling = true;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Here’s the React interface connecting smart contract with Metamask.

UI Interface..

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import GlobalStyles from '@mui/material/GlobalStyles';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { Footer, Navbar } from "./components";
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import QRCode from 'react-qr-code';
import abi from './components/abi';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';


function LaunchpadApp() {

  // Important steps:
  // 1- Create presale address using https://...com/
  // 2- Send the tokens for presale to the presale contact address
  // 3- Update the following constants with your presale details
  const presaleAddress = “0x039a**************d”;
  const rate = 3500;
  const presaleTokens = 1000000;
  const tokenDecimals = 18;
  

  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState(null);
  const [amountText, setAmountText] = useState(0);
  const [remaingTokens, setRemaingTokens] = useState(presaleTokens);

  let payAmount = "0";

  const handleAmountChange = (event) => {
    setAmountText(event.target.value);
    if(Number(event.target.value) > 0){
    }
  };


  const checkWalletIsConnected = () => {
    const { ethereum } = window;
    if(!ethereum){
      console.log("Metamask NOT Installed");
      return;
    }else{
      console.log("Metamask Installed");
    }
   }

  const connectWalletHandler = async() => { 
    const { ethereum } = window;
    if(!ethereum){
      alert("Please Install Metamask!");
    }

    try{
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
      console.log("Found an account :", accounts[0]);
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
    }catch (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  const connectWalletButton = () => {
    return (
      <Button onClick={connectWalletHandler} variant="contained" fullWidth align="center">
        Wallet Connect
      </Button>
    )
  }

  const buyButton = () => {
    return (
      <Button onClick={buyHandler} variant="contained" fullWidth align="center">
        Buy
      </Button>
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkWalletIsConnected();
  }, [])

  const getRemainingTokens = async() => {
    try{
      const { ethereum } = window;

      if(ethereum){
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(presaleAddress, abi, signer);

        let tokensNum = String(await contract.tokenBalance())
        tokensNum = tokensNum.substring(0,tokensNum.length - tokenDecimals);
        setRemaingTokens(Number(tokensNum));
      }
    }catch(err){
        alert("You need to connect with MetaMask.");
        console.log(err);
    }

  }

  getRemainingTokens();
  


  const buyHandler = async() => {
    try{
      const { ethereum } = window;

      if(ethereum){
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(presaleAddress, abi, signer);

        console.log("Intialize payment");
        payAmount = String(Number(amountText) * 1000000000000000000);
        let buyDone = await contract.buyTokens({value: payAmount});
        console.log(contract);
        if(buyDone){
            alert("Congratulations, you will receive your tokens very soon");
        }else{
            alert("Something is wrong, Maybe you don't have enough BNB on your balance.");
        }
      }
    }catch(err){
          alert("Something is wrong, Maybe you don't have enough BNB on your balance.");
        console.log(err);
    }

  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyles styles={{ ul: { margin: 0, padding: 0, listStyle: 'none' } }} />
      <CssBaseline />
        <Navbar />
      {/* Hero unit */}
      <Container disableGutters maxWidth="lg" component="main" sx={{ pt: 8, pb: 6 }}>
        <Typography
          component="h1"
          variant="h4"
          align="center"
          color="text.primary"
          gutterBottom
        >
          Firenza Presale I
        </Typography>
      </Container>
      {/* End hero unit */}
      <Container maxWidth="lg" component="main">
        <Grid container spacing={3} alignItems="flex">
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
            <img src=“https://.....com/logo_black.png” alt="ethrx" width={60} border="0"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={11}>
              <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
                Firenza (FRX) is a Utility Token.
             </Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Token Name: Firenza FRX
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Symbol: FRX
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Token Address: 0x6Fe10************e2f
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
 <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Presale Address: {presaleAddress}
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Tokens For Pre-Sale: 2,000,000
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Tokens For Liquidity : 8,000,000
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Tokenlock: 30 days
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        <Typography variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
          Presale Start Time: 2023.18.04 06:00 (UTC)
        </Typography>
        <br/>
        <Divider />
        <br/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Box sx={{ border: 1, borderColor: 'grey.500', borderRadius: 1 }}>
            <Typography variant="h6" align="center" color="text.secondary" component="p">
            MetaMask Buy
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{m:2}} variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
              Rate: 1 BNB = {rate} FRX
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{m:2}} variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
              Tokens For Presale : 2,000,000
            </Typography>
            <LinearProgress sx={{m:2}} variant="determinate" value={String(((presaleTokens-remaingTokens)/presaleTokens))*100} />
            <Box sx={{m:2}}>
              <TextField value={amountText} onChange={handleAmountChange} fullWidth label="Amount in BNB" type="number" required />
            </Box>
            <Typography sx={{m:2}} variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
              Get : {amountText * rate} FRX
            </Typography>
            <Box sx={{m:2}}>
              {currentAccount ? buyButton() : connectWalletButton()}
            </Box>
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ border: 1, borderColor: 'grey.500', borderRadius: 1, mt:2 }}>
            <Typography variant="h6" align="center" color="text.secondary" component="p">
              Direct Buy
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{m:2}} variant="p" align="left" color="text.secondary" component="p">
              Send BNB direct to the presale address below using the QR code and you will receive FRX tokens immediately.
            </Typography>
            <Box sx={{m:2}} align="center">
              <QRCode
                title="Presale QR"
                value={presaleAddress}
              />
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
      {/* Footer */}
      <Footer />
      {/* End footer */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default function Launchpad() {
  return <LaunchpadApp />;
}
```

Is there a bug? Do or did I miss something?
Thanks in advance.
JayJay

Comment: Please post the error messages as well